# iOS - How to not present model view if it is presenting?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, presentviewcontroller

I have a floating button to present a model view. I call presentViewController in AppDelegate

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController!.getTopViewController().presentViewController(myViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

When myViewController is presenting, I click my floating button again and my application will call myViewController one more time. So how to not present if it presenting?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a check on your button to check whether the present controller is presenting something which can be done like this

```
let controller = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController!.getTopViewController()

if controller.presentedViewController == nil {
       controller.presentViewController(myViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```